# Swift mail and Symfony ([Connection refused #111])

Tags: email, symfony1, swiftmailer

I am getting this error when I try to send an email using the Symfony framework. I had this problem a while back and rember (vaguely), that I had to change my php.ini settings and match them to my /app/config/factories.yml to get it to work.

Unfortunately, I had to rebuild my machine recently, and mail has now stopped working - and unfortunately, I can't remember what I did the last time to get ot to work.

Here is a snippet of the contents of my app/config/factories.yml file:

```
all:
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
      delivery_strategy: realtime
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        param:
          host:       localhost
          port:       25
          encryption: ~
          username:   ~
          password:   ~
```

Note: The indentaion above may be wrong due to being pasted in this console - don't get side tracked by that. The YML is fine on my machine.

This is the logged error message when I try to send an email:

```
[19-Feb-2011 14:50:13] PHP  20. userActions->executeRegisterComplete() /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.8/lib/action/sfActions.class.php:60
[19-Feb-2011 14:50:13] PHP  21. sfMailer->send() /path/to/actions.class.php:355
[19-Feb-2011 14:50:13] PHP  22. Swift_Mailer->send() /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.8/lib/mailer/sfMailer.class.php:300
[19-Feb-2011 14:50:13] PHP  23. Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.8/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Mailer.php:74
[19-Feb-2011 14:50:13] PHP  24. Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize() /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.8/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:101
[19-Feb-2011 14:50:13] PHP  25. Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.8/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:70
[19-Feb-2011 14:50:13] PHP  26. fsockopen() /lib/vendor/symfony/symfony-1.3.8/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:233
[19-Feb-2011 14:50:13] Connection could not be established with host localhost [Connection refused #111]
```

Comment: Do you recall your fix involving installing/configuring a mail server (that listens on port 25) on your machine? Because it looks like the problem is that there isn't one listening there at the moment...

Comment: That would have been my answer too. Install postfix and have another go.

Answer (score 5):

I've always put like and always have worked;
I simply do not use localhost smtp service.

```
all:
  mailer:
    param:
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        param:
          host:       smtp.gmail.com
          port:       465
          encryption: ssl
          username: "xxx@gmail.com"
          password: xxx-password
```

Comment: had to add encryption/port myself to make it work with `Mailjet`

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that you do not have disabled the mail sent in development environment. You have to complete your **config_dev.yml** like this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: true

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type:  firephp
            level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: true

swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: true
```

You have to set:

- **disable_delivery: true** (not send email)
- **intercept_redirects: true** (if you want to see the email in your debug bar)

Comment: You're talking about sf2.0 where he seems to use sf1.3

Answer (score 0):

I had same error on my hosting provider. I have fixed it by editing factories.yml indentation. Also check your username/password values.